# What does 生命诚可贵 爱情价更高 若为自由故 二者皆可抛 mean?

Tags: meaning

> 生命诚可贵 爱情价更高 若为自由故 二者皆可抛

I think it means "life is expensive, but love is even more so.  However, both are not as good as freedom."

Answer (score 15):

It's a little different from yours at the latter half of the sentence:

> Life is dear, love is dearer. Both can be given up for freedom.

Reference:

This is the poem written in 1847 by the Hungarian poet [Sándor Petőfi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A1ndor_Pet%C5%91fi#Poetry). Here is the original:

> Szabadság, szerelem!
>   E kettő kell nekem.
>   Szerelmemért föláldozom
>   Az életet, Szabadságért föláldozom Szerelmemet.

Here's the translation by [殷夫](http://baike.baidu.com/view/41436.htm) in 1929, which adopted Chinese classic five-character poem style, but not totally faithful to the original text:

> 生命诚可贵，
>   爱情价更高。
>   若为自由故，
>   二者皆可抛。

Another translation by [孙用](http://baike.baidu.com/subview/575815/10240576.htm) in 1957:

> 自由，爱情！
>   我要的就是这两样。
>   为了爱情，
>   我牺牲我的生命；
>   为了自由，
>   我又将爱情牺牲。

Another translation by [兴万生](http://baike.baidu.com/view/1044858.htm) in 1991:

> 自由与爱情！
>   我都为之倾心。
>   为了爱情，
>   我宁愿牺牲生命，
>   为了自由，
>   我宁愿牺牲爱情。

In English:

> Liberty and love
>   These two I must have
>   For love, I will sacrifice my life
>   For liberty, I will sacrifice my love

Answer (score 0):

It's a poem which is translated by 殷夫 from Petogfi's "freedom and love".
The English version is here:

> **Freedom and love**
>
> These two I must have
>
> For love, I will
>
> sacrifice my life;
>
> For liberty, I will
>
> sacrifice my love

Answer (score -2):

Is that really an old Chinese saying?

生命诚可贵 爱情价更高 若为自由故 二者皆可抛。

Life is precious, love's worth more, but for freedom both would I abandon.

Sounds like someone who wants to be a very lonely old man! Although, maybe its not from someone who wants a divorce, but a soldier before the battle.